# Scala - select elements from ordered list

Tags: list, scala

I am looking for a nice way to remove first N elements which are equal from the ordered list, e.g.

```
List(1,1,1,2,3,3)
```

should return

```
removeSame(list)  -> (1,1,1)
```

Is there a nice way to do it, rather than remove the head of the list and then use `takeWhile` on the remainder, and finally using `dropwhile`? I can think of simple non-functional solution but I was wondering whether any functional one also exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functional way to avoid the duplication of `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` to get a prefix and remainder is using `span`, i.e.

```
scala> val list = List(1,1,1,2,3,3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)

scala> val (prefix, rest) = list span (_ == list.head)
prefix: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1)
rest: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you look for?

```
scala> val l = List(1,1,1,2,3,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)

scala> l.takeWhile(_ == l.head)
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1)

scala> val l = List()
l: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> l.takeWhile(_ == l.head)
res7: List[Nothing] = List()
```

Comment: SOrry, would you mind modifying that to deal with `Iterator` rather than than the list? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way of doing it, but this also works:

```
def removeSame(l: List) = if( !l.isEmpty) l.groupBy( x => x)(l.head) else List()
```